# VBA Excel populate single cell with listbox items

Tags: vba, excel

How can I pass all the items in a listbox to a single cell with comma delimiter in VBA?

Here's my current code, where I pass each item to an array, then set the cell value to the array, but it doesn't work.

```
        Dim histReturn() As Long
        Dim j As Integer
        For j = 0 To Me.history_lbx.ListCount - 1
            ReDim Preserve histReturn(j)
        Dim x As Variant
        For Each x In histReturn
            Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i, 4).Value & x & ", "
        Next x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use an array, you should not redim in a loop, but once and for all, since you know the dimension : `ReDim histReturn(history.ListCount)` for example. But your array never gets any value, so when your second loop try to find ListBox items in it, it can't.

Here is an idea, looping to get ListBox items, adding to a String, then putting the result in a Cell.

```
Dim S As String
If history_lbx.ListCount = 0 Then
    Cells(1, 1).Value = ""
Else
    S = history_lbx.List(0)
    For i = 2 To history_lbx.ListCount
        S = S & ", " & history_lbx.List(i - 1)
    Next i
    Cells(1, 1).Value = S
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to loop at all.  You can use `Join` to create the comma delimited list, like this

```
Sub Demo
    Dim rng as Range
    Set rng = Cells(1, 1)

    If history_lbx.ListCount = 0 Then
        rng = vbNullString
    Else
        rng = Join(Application.Transpose(history_lbx.List), ",")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: this line gives a type mismatch error:
`rng = Join(Application.Transpose(history_lbx), ",")`

Comment: Editied answer.  Typo, missing reference to `List` in `Application.Transpose(history_lbx.List)`